# Which strategy did the fund most likely follow?

Tags: data, curve-fitting, homework

The following time series represents the return stream of a real hedge fund. Which
strategy did the fund most likely follow?
[image]

I did this data superimposition on Matlab. So, there should be some data analysis process that is able to find the best fit. Regression is not working well. And the hedge fund returns are not normally distributed.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried Sharpe Style Analysis. It is similar to but different from regression, in particular the weights in SSA are constrained to be positive. Mathematically SSA is a Quadratic minimization subject to >= 0 constraints. It may yield better results; even so Hedge Funds can be more difficult to categorize than most types of portfolio due to their ability to change strategy.